# Stomp box losing power issue

Tags: effects-pedal, electronics, repair

I have a new stomp box (to me; purchased used from a friend).  Since some may ask, it's a Big Muff Pi, recent NYC Reissue (the big red and silver one).

I used it for a few days without issue.  Then, over the past week, when I go to use it, I stomp it on and the red light slowly goes dim and off, as the fuzz effect stops working.

My buddy said he put a new battery in it, but I thought I would replace it just in case.  Now it has gone from not working at first, but working after a few stomps; to, not working at all.

Does this behavior sound familiar to anyone, whether for all stomp boxes, or maybe even this make and model?

Edit turned to an answer.

Comment: So, up until you replaced the battery it would always flash briefly, and as soon as you had the new battery in it doesn't do even that anymore?

Comment: Most pedals using batteries are turned on when a jack is inserted. Leave that jack in, the battery will go flat. Have you tried a power souce instead (9VDC)? There may be a bad connection on a jack socket, not allowing enough current to flow through. Give everything a spray with switch cleaner - including the footswitch. Ask your friend why he didn't get on with it..!

Comment: will do.  I will try a 9V tonight.  I am sure to disengage all jacks when I'm done for the day.

Comment: @Tim Thanks. I just jostled the input jack and was able to get the LED to come in and out. How do you recommend I clean the ports, and do you think the lead might be bad?  By the way, it wasn't the wall wart.  No difference there.

Comment: The jack could also have broken loose from the PC board inside. If that's the case, and you're not familiar with soldering, then refer servicing to qualified personnel.

Comment: Talked to my buddy about these suggestions.  He said it's fairly new, and shouldn't require deep cleaning in the ports.  He suspects that there is a short in the DC jack.  And he's qualified; he'll be soldering for me.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Repair Post Mortem*

My buddy did, in fact take it back and look at what was happening.  There was a wire exposed that connected the battery and the DC port.  He did a neat rig-up.  He taped up the leads in this area, and made the battery an external connection.  The battery now connects to the DC port with such a connector.

And if I want to use a DC wall wart instead, I just remove the connector.  Now I don't need to take the case apart to change the battery.  A bit unsightly, but I am pleased with the outcome.

*Years later...*

I am only using a power supply now for all my pedals, so the rigging that my buddy did isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

To add on Tim's comment: most stompbox are turned on when an input jack is connected. The important point is that, even if you are in true bypass mode (led off) some pedals are still draining some power, even though it’s not being used. The power path is not always shutdown by the switch.

As you said that you "stomped" on it to turn it on, you probably left the Jack in, draining the battery. The pedal was never completely off, just in bypass.